# fopen on file through FTP URL

Tags: php, download, fopen, feof

I am trying to download a file using PHP from an FTP URL, which looks like `ftp://username:password@domain/file.zip` . 
The URL is good, because I can download the file pasting it into any browser.
Fopen supports this kind of file streaming, just saw it here: [fopen](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php) .
Here's my code:

```
[...]
$destination_folder = '../importmlsupload/';    
$url = "ftp://user:password@domain/file.zip";
$newfname = $destination_folder . basename($url);
$file = fopen($url, "rb");
if ($file) {
    $newf = fopen($newfname, "wb");
    while(!feof($file)) {
        $s = fread($file, 1024);
        fwrite($newf, $s, 1024 );
    }
}

if (!empty($file)) {
    fclose($file);
}

if (!empty($newf)) {
    fclose($newf);
}
```

**The problem** is that I get an ampty file downloaded. I have made some verifications and I got the following results: the file is been created successfully on the server, but the while loop (!feof(...)) ends after the first step. So it reads 1024 bytes and it exits from the loop. By other words feof returns true after the first 1024 bytes or reading.

**TRYING WITH HTTP URL RESULTS SUCCESSFUL IMPORT, BUT FTP URL DOESN'T**

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2):

I did not try your code, but if you have ftp details, you can use [FTP functions](http://php.net/manual/en/book.ftp.php) instead. This might not be the appropriate answer i know. :)

Comment: thank you I appreciate, if I wont got an easy resolution for this one then I'll use them.

Answer (score 1):

Hi Ervin and sorry for the late answer!

I just had the same problem and I found actually two answers. First I tried `file_get_contents`. This works like this:

```
$input = file_get_contents($url);
$writtenChars = file_put_contents($newfname, $input);
```

Very simple and works, but I guess just for ASCII and if you have quite some memory as this reads the whole file before writing it. I liked your approach with buffer. So I did the following:

```
$source = fopen($url, 'r');
$destination = fopen($newfname, 'w+');
while($data = fread($source, 1024)) {
    fwrite($destination, $data);
}
```

This works fine for the XML file I'm downloading. Your binary should be fine when you do your `'wb'` in the *mode parameter* of `fopen`.

I don't know why your `feof` doesn't work, sorry. But as you see in my code, you don't need it anyway.